# Default attributes for UITextView

Tags: swift, uitextview

UITextView's seem to use whatever the first character in it's attributedText's attributes as the default attributes for any text that follows. I've tried to use typingAttributes but that only works when typing (pasting and double tapping space bar are the issues I'll explain shortly).

If I created a mention as the first line of text and then pasted text the pasted text would have the mention attributes.

If however, I added text (default attributes) followed by a mention, and then pasted text the pasted text would have the default attributes.

I've tried to reset typingAttributes which works if you're typing after the mention but anytime you paste or double tap the space bar and add the `.` it will take the attributes of whatever the first character is.

Is there any way to handle this? Possibly an NSAttributedString function to override or any method/var on UITextView that I'm missing that might help me?

First edit:

Capturing text that's longer than 1 character inside of

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange,
                         replacementText text: String) -> Bool
```

allows me to return false and replace the text myself.

I am however stuck trying to capture the change from two spaces to a `.`

If anyone knows how to properly capture this it would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my edit to solve my issue with pasting text I used

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange,
                         replacementText text: String) -> Bool
```

and captured text over 1 character and inserted it myself with the proper attributes and return false.

As for the double tapping of the space bar my solution (for the moment at least) is to check

```
public func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)
```

and see (based on the selectedRange location and two characters back) whether or not we now have a period and a space. If we do I put a default text attribute for that location. This may not work for everyone since there may be occasions where a period and a space shouldn't be set to defaults. For the moment that doesn't appear to be an issue for me but if it is I will post my work around here.

Comment: Interesting, I totally didn't think about the pasting + double tap with period issue! Thanks for following up. It's rare to see a SO answer with a proper follow up. I'm still curious to why this behaviour changed in the iOS 11 though.

Comment: I don't believe this is specific to iOS 11 but rather an issue that's gone under the radar.